# Mercedes E-350, 2006 sedan ignition problem

Tags: starting, ignition, mercedes-benz

I own a Mercedes e-350 2006 sedan whose ignition box was vandalized and taken away by vandals. I could not start this car since then and I thought of buying a used ignition box to use on the car with the original key but will this work? If not what other options can I explore to get this car started?

Answer (score 3):

As it's a security-specific component on a relatively new high-end car, I suspect you won't be able to use a second-hand part - You will probably have to get a new one from Mercedes. Even if you could use a second-hand one, you'll almost certainly have to take it to Mercedes to get them to reprogram it to your car.